# GWT and views. How does this work?

Tags: gwt

I have done some seen some basic GWT tutorial but thats just one page. How does GWT applications with many pages work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GWT you have on Page, where everything happens. If you want to load a subpage, then this happens by AJAX Request.

So that means you have a navigation panel (exp. News and Contanct) and a content panel, where the content will be rendered.

So you click on News and the News-content will be rendered in the content panel. Or you click on Contact, the contact-content will be rendered in the content panel.

You don't have page reloads, only partial reloads.

Read [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture), to know how it works.

Answer (score 1):

How does GWT applications with many pages work?

As you know GWT is a single page application. With help of History mechanism, you can show one then more page like behaviour.

Refer link:

- [History Mechanism in GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory)